# Debian UART Dropping Bytes

Tags: linux-kernel, debian, beagleboneblack, uart

**Situation:**
I'm trying to manipulate/hack a Debian kernel to be able to use 9-bit UART via the parity hack that you can find reference to everywhere on the NET. Now for some reason Tx is working just fine, but when we look at Rx we're dropping bytes. We're expecting 9 bytes back, including the crc, but we get a variable amount back between 4-7. It will vary with the exact same code run a few times in a row, so it almost appears to be buffer related. Hooking it up to the logic analyzer the response is proper(9 expected bytes) from the slave device, but it is getting "mangled" somewhere low level that I can't track down.

**Attempted:**
So I started dumping all the bytes(char) that come in here:

```
static void serial_omap_rdi(struct uart_omap_port *up, unsigned int lsr)
```

Which still results in only seeing 4-7 bytes of bad data. I'm assuming this is due to parity/framing/FIFO errors but I just can't seem to get any deeper to where I can see exactly where it's failing.

**Questions:**
Has anyone seen anything like this type of discarded data on the UART line with a linux kernel? If so would you know any possible avenues to take in tracking it down?

Is there anyplace in the kernel I can look to actually dump the bit-by-bit data that is coming into the UART Rx line?

Any help is greatly appreciated as I'm at my wits end understanding how/where exactly the kernel is discarding these bytes...

**Platform:**
BBB Debian Linux 3.8.13-bone53 armv7l GNU/Linux
16750 UART (I Believe)

Comment: The serial driver can be configured to discard (drop) bytes that have parity errors. Have you checked how the termios for the port is set up? See: http://linux.die.net/man/3/termios and note the part about PARMRK and IGNPAR

Comment: Thanks for the input! Unfortunately yes I've looked into setting IGNPAR and PARMRK. I've tried many different combinations of options for termios, but still can't get any better results. That's why I'm looking to actually get to the deepest level I can to actually analyze at a bit-by-bit level of the Rx comm.Or at least locate where in the kernel these values would be getting discarded due to an error... but very little luck thus far.

Comment: The bit-by-bit level is handled by the 16550 (or compatible) UART hardware and the kernel knows nothing about it. The kernel simply reads the registers from the UART when the UART signals that it has received a byte (or bytes in FIFO buffer mode). While googling "linux serial driver parity error" when writing the comment above I came across this debian forum post which may give you some clues: http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=73873

Comment: Okay, so the the hardware handles the bit-by-bit to byte level conversion, and sends an interrupt to the kernel to signal it has a byte, but it would still be up to the kernel to then process and either keep/discard this byte correct?

Comment: That I'm not sure about. 10 years ago, when I was designing firmware, I'd be more sure because back then I use the 16550 a lot. I know that the kernel reads a register within the UART to figure out if any errors have occured. But I'm not sure if the data byte in the FIFO would be valid or not. In theory I see no reason for the hardware designer to deliberately make it not valid. But reading the datasheet I can't find any mention of the behavior. I think your best bet is to write a special device driver to use the UART in 9 bit mode then do some tests.

Comment: Yeah my main goal here to simply figure out at what point we're actually loosing the bytes that we're seeing come through the analyzer.. unfortunately I'm not linux-kernel savvy enough to dig my way through this. I'll keep attempting though.

Comment: *"So I started dumping all the bytes(char) that come in here: **static void serial_omap_rdi()**"* --  You're looking at only the received bytes that do not have errors.  When there's a receive-error (e.g. parity, framing) interrupt, **serial_omap_rlsi()** is called.  BTW Rx data errors get handled differently depending on whether DMA or PIO is used for storing the bytes from the UART.

Comment: I survived my final year of Uni with this: https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/. I actually bought the hardcopy but these days it's also available online. I do still recommend getting a hardcopy if you're likely to be doing a lot of low-level hardware stuff - you'll be thumbing through it a lot.

Comment: Wow, awesome resource slebetman, and thank you for the info sawdust. Will be looking into both of these very soon!